# glade import error as a gtk.glade

Tags: 14.04, gtk, python3, glade

I am trying to port Python 2 to Python 3, but I am having trouble importing Glade:

```
import gtk.glade 
ImportError: cannot import name glade, introspection typelib not found
```

Any idea how to fix this?
 
Thanks

Comment: Try replacing that import line with this: `from gi.repository import gtk.glade`

Comment: I tired : from gi.repository import gtk.glad  getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                                          from gi.repository import Gtk.glad  getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you doing this from command line?

Comment: No. In source code script.py file

Comment: hm okay Im not sure, never seen a SyntaxError with from before

Comment: Do I need to install any packages to resolve this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31527/discussion-between-david-cole-and-mrudula).

Comment: It's not duplicate!! I have some other problem. Not gtk inport problem. Could you please look into it carefully. Here I have posted about glade not gtk. I am able to import gtk. But stiil not able to import glade. Any idea?